# IvyDE unresolved dependency

Tags: ivy, artifactory, ivyde

I am using artifactory, Eclipse and IvyDE to pull in jar files. I have the following dependency in my ivy.xml

```
<dependency org="org.apache.activemq" name="activemq-camel" rev="5.9.0.redhat-610379"/>
```

but I am getting the following IvyDE error

unresolved dependency: org.apache.activemq#activemq-camel;5.9.0.redhat-610379: not found

I can go to artifactory and find the jar file. It gives me the ivy.xml entry needed to pull it but I am getting this error. I was thinking maybe the rev is invalid?

Thanks!

Comment: I just tried putting latest.release in the rev and it pulled the previous release. That is, rev 5.5.1. Clearly, 5.9.0 is later.

Comment: Version doesn't exist in Maven Central. Perhaps this is an artifact locally hosted in your artifactory instance. See: http://search.maven.org/#search|gav|1|g%3A%22org.apache.activemq%22%20AND%20a%3A%22activemq-camel%22

Comment: Have you configured IvyDE so its uses the ivysettings.xml pointing to your artifactory ?